# LWC Button pass a value to the JS Method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, button

I have a two buttons defined in my LWC

```
 <lightning-button
      variant="brand-outline"
      label="Age"
      title="Age"
      onclick={handleClick}
      class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"
      data-id="age"
    ></lightning-button>

    <lightning-button
      variant="brand-outline"
      label="Name"
      title="Name"
      customvalue="customValue"
      onclick={handleClick}
      class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"
      data-id="name"
    ></lightning-button>
```

In my JS I have the following method

```
handleClick(event){
console.log(event.target.name)  //doesn't work
console.log(event) //doesn't work
console.log(this) //doesn't work
console.log(tis.name) // doesn't work
}
```

The end goal I'm seeking is to know which of the two buttons have been pushed so I can have my code behave accordingly.

How do I do detect which button was clicked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LWC components dispatch a `CustomEvent`

To get data out of this component, the convention is to look for

`event.detail.value` if it's a publicly exposed value on that component.

If you are in the same shadow tree, you can use `event.target.value`

In your instance, you need to use `detail.value` to get the value, because you can't see inside that component.

If you wanted to get data-id="age" from the event, you should use:

```
event.target.dataset.id
```

[more details here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_best_practices)

Comment: yes it works so thank you for that.  What confuses me now is how ```data-id="name"``` in the HTML turns into ```event.target.dataset.id``` in javascript.  I also tried event.target.dataset.???? for several other values I thought would work and it didn't.

Comment: `dataset.val` only works for values that you define. The syntax goes from `data-your-var="x"` to `event.target.dataset.yourVar` - notice the camelcase.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this to check the value:

```
ageValue;
nameValue;

handleClick(event){
if(event.target.dataset.id  === 'age'){
        this.ageValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.ageValue);
        }
else if(event.target.dataset.id  === 'name'){
        this.nameValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.nameValue);
}
}
```